# A fundamental question on optimal stopping time need clarification

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance-mathematics, stopping-time

I am currently studying optimal stopping time.Under this topic there is a basic concept which confuses me. I would appreciate some clarification.
So we define $\tau$ a stopping time, and $\phi (\tau,x_t)$ being the pay off function that realises the optimal value function $$V(t,x)=\, sup_{t\leqslant \tau \leq T}\, E_{t,x}[\phi (\tau,x_t) ]$$ Firstly I don't understand both the mathematical and finance implication of this?
$$E_{t,x}[\cdot ]\rightarrow x_{t}=x$$
Secondly,I don't understand that if I have a strategy that waits until $t+\Delta t$ then uses$\tau_{t+\Delta t}$ , why is the value of this strategy $$E_{t,x}[V(x_{t+\Delta t},\tau_{t+\Delta t})]$$instead of $$V(x_{t+\Delta t},\tau_{t+\Delta t})?$$ This brings the question of at what time point $t$ are we evaluating all these stopping time strategy?
Lastly, I would like to know if this 
$$V(x_{t},\tau_{t})\ge E_{t,x}[V(x_{t+\Delta t},\tau_{t+\Delta t})]$$is purely based on the assumption of supermartingale property?